# Upsell and cross sell opportunity via recommender system

Tags: recommender-system, k-means, k-nn

I have a million residential  customers across the United States who purchase my service. Some buy a single service, some buy multiple services.

I want to identify similar customers who are alike in every way except they buy different services. My intent is to identify the similar customers and market to them the services that they do not buy

I initially thought to employ user-user collaborative filtering. But “ratings” on my service do not strike me as relevant for this task - it is demographic and location similarities I believe apply

My thought now is to utilize k means clustering to cluster similar customers. Then identify product purchase variance among them and use that information to cross and upsell.

In this, K means becomes the center of my solution.

What else should I be thinking about in terms of generating a more complete recommender system?